# The datetime I'm consuming does not appear as I expect. Why?

Tags: c#, web-services

A third-party web service (Java) is returning the time as below:

```
1970-01-01T23:00:00.000+10:00
```

When I consume the web service via WCF Storm it shows:

```
1970-01-02 12:00:00 AM
```

Could someone please clarify what's happening here? I would have thought it should be:

```
1970-01-02 9:00:00 AM
```

Comment: How do you consume and get the value ?

Comment: `1970-01-02 12:00:00 AM` is `1970-01-01T23:00:00.000+10:00` converted to your local time zone.  I'm assuming you're in +11GMT.